# Changing numbers to labels in R

Tags: r, switch-statement

I have a data frame with a column `time` which contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. I want to convert these to labels, so 1 goes to "8hr", 2 goes to "12hr", etc. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: did you try 'paste()'?

Comment: Something like this? `df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 3)); df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), labels = c('8hr', '12hr', '16hr', '20hr', '24hr', '28hr'))`